# Linux grep -e command

Tags: linux, grep

In a makefile, there is a command line:

```
COUNT=`grep -e "->" < "$(SOME_DIR)/count.log" | wc -l` ;
```

Here I want to know, if the < occur in this command represent output redirect,and if the count.log file is empty, should it report a error info.

Thanks，

Comment: Just wonder... it should work by simply `grep -e "->" "$(SOME_DIR)/count.log" | wc -l` (without redirection).  It looks clearer

Answer (score 1):

`<` represents *input* redirection. `grep`'s standard input is attached to the `count.log` file. It is not an error if `count.log` is empty, but it is an error if `count.log` does not exist.

Comment: I get it.Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tests I have performed for your reference:

When there is no *count.log* file, the result is:

```
# grep -e "->" < "count.log" | wc -l
-bash: count.log: No such file or directory
0
```

When there is an empty *count.log* file, the result is:

```
# touch count.log
# grep -e "->" < "count.log" | wc -l
0
```

When there is a matching pattern, the result is:

```
# echo "->" > count.log
# grep -e "->" < "count.log" | wc -l
1
```

Therefore, you will only get an error if the file does not exist.

Comment: Thank you for your help!